# Multiple emails selected messageMetadata.accessToken

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Is it possible to process multiple selected emails by an addon?
The code from Google shows how to process only one selected email. I suppose 'e' would be some kind of array of accesstokens but I don't know how to access it.

```
function getContextualAddOn(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  Logger.log("token:"+ accessToken);
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;

  var card = createCard();
  return [card.build()];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think add-ons are even able to be opened upon just *selecting* an email - I believe you can only trigger your add-on by opening an email.

Comment: Hi, yes that's right but you can read through all types of email within your addin even when you open the addin with only one. For example, selecting all emails with a certain label, or all emails that are starred. There doesn't seem to be an option to select all that have been ticked, i.e. the checkbox enabled.

Comment: And that's what I stated. "ticking" / selecting emails is not the same as opening one, and then selecting your addon.

Comment: You are not understanding the question: I know you can trigger an addon by opening just one email but WITHIN the addon code, you can select other emails, e.g. all emails with a certain label, or all emails that have been starred.
So here is the scenario: you tick 5 emails, then you open one email then you open the addon. Within the addon, you select all emails that have been ticked, i.e. 5 emails.
You can select the 5 emails if they had the same label or were starred for xample, but I do not see a way of selecting emails that are ticked.
Hope that is clearer.

Comment: Again, you are not understanding the question.

Comment: Edit your question to improve it, to avoid further misunderstandings

Comment: No, I think you need to think before answering :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your Apps Script code never runs on the client device, where the messages are selected in the Gmail UI - it runs on Google's servers. You can't access UI information from add-ons (there's no [`GmailApp.getSelectedThreads()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/#methods), [`CardService.getActiveEmails()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service#methods), etc.). You are only able to access the *opened* message / draft, and others in the same thread (or mailbox, depending on your [add-on's scopes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/scopes#gmail_add-on_scopes)).

The [event object](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/actions#action_event_objects) received by your triggered callback function will only have a single access token. Until [additional manifest triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#manifest_triggers) are added (currently only [`contextual`](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui) and [`compose`](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui) exist), this won't change.

As this is not Google, no one here can tell you if or when other triggers may or may not be added. You best bet is to [request the feature](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail-support?nav=true#missing_features).

Comment: Hi,
Ok thanks tehhowch, that was my question. Because there are methods like getUserLabelByName, getStarredThreads etc. to access other emails even though you only opened one, it seemed strange that there is no "getCheckedThreads" method. 
But from what you're saying, Starred Threads might be a flag on Google's servers whereas ticking a checkbox is just a client UI action which isn't accessible from appscripts, although it could be argued I suppose that Starring a thread is also a client UI action.

But anyway, you answered the question. Thanks!