# Getting thread id's of selected Emails in Gmail, using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I am currently working on creating a Gmail Add-on. For this Add-on I would very much like to get the Thread Id's of the Threads/Mails I select in my inbox.

I have been looking extensively through the reference and the examples, but can't find any way of doing this?

When I open a thread/mail I get a trigger which sends an event object to my script, from where I can get the current mails Thread Id. But I can't seem to get an action trigger from selecting the mails or otherwise access the id's of selected mails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or is this just not doable?

Kind regards

Dennis Schmock

[image: Picture here]

Comment: Nope, not possible. Selected mails is UI-only currently.

Comment: I can't propose your question as duplicate without an upvote / accept of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52543393/9337071), but it seems like this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Tehhowch. Thank you for clarifying that for me. That was my conclusion as well after really digging in to their reference, but I had to make sure, that there wasn't something I missed. 

I will have to try another approach then - I am thinking something along the line of marking threads I want with a special label, and processing them instead. 

Thank you very much, for your answer :-)

Comment: Unfortunately my rep is still to low to upvote, but if you submit your comment as an answer, I will make it THE accepted answer :-)

Comment: @tehhowch any progress regarding this?